# Regulate image sizes in Yahoo Pipes output

Tags: yahoo, yahoo-pipes

When combining multiple blog feeds into one using Yahoo Pipes, is it possible to control the image sizes in the output?

I've seen the existing operators and filters offered, but there doesn't seem to be an option that e.g. rejects a post from my feed if its image is >500px wide, or even resizes that image to a given size.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by the way - the solution is to use the Regex module to substitute existing width and height values for new ones. See this pipe: http://pipes.yahoo.com/strangerpixel/lcfcombo.